# HTML Content Parsing

Tags: c#, linq, html-parsing

I have two code for getting no of characters inside templates first one is

```
string html = this.GetHTMLContent(url);

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlTextNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
{
    sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText);
}
string final = sb.ToString();
int lenght = final.Length;
```

And second one is

```
var length = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")
                .Where(x => x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
                .Select(x => x.InnerText.Length)
                .Sum();
```

When I run both code return me different result.

Comment: The first attempt reads the InnerText of each node, the second selects only nodes that have a specific NodeType. I'd expect there is at least one node that *isn't* `HtmlNodeType.Text` in there. Where is the test input?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just removed my where condition but output same.

Comment: You can use Say my input parameter value is string url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22711830/html-content-parsing?noredirect=1#comment34608830_22711830"; as input parameter value

Comment: Did you try to simply compare the two strings?

Comment: I tried but there are huge amount of characters more than 70000 so it is little bit complex task

Comment: Either try with a smaller input or extract them to a file and compare them with a diff tool

Comment: Did you found any logical difference between those code? I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I identified the problem. the problem was inside loop I used appendLine() method instead of append() method. so it appended new line each time of looping. So that some white spaces it also recognized as character.